# HL7 RXE10 Segment definition

Tags: hl7

Is RXE10 (**Dispense Amount**) means dispense amount by the machines or dispense amount to the patient?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RXE-10` is dispense amount from the machine, as requested.